# Logging in Json format from Vert.x application

Tags: json, performance, logging, vert.x, reactive

We recently migrated from Splunk to ELK. We wanted to log our message as json for better searchability in Kibana.

Our application was using vert.x 3.9. I came across https://reactiverse.io/reactiverse-contextual-logging but that requires vertx-core to be updated to 4.x. This will be a major change for us and I looked for other options. Also, I joined this team recently and new to Vert.x

I came across `net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder` and able to log the messages as json. I used `io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject` to convert my message and key values to convert to json. I created a wrapper class that returns the string for given message and key/values as shown below.

```
public class KeyValueLogger {
    public static String getLog(final String message) {
        return new JsonObject().put("message", message).encode();
    }

    public static String getLog(final String message, final Map<String, Object> params) {
        return new JsonObject().put("message", message).mergeIn(new JsonObject(params)).encode();
    }
}
```

Every log message will call the above KeyValueLogger.getLog to get json message. Since Vert.x is a reactive application, is there a better solution to convert the log messages to json? Most of the log messages are in worker threads. I am afraid if any is in event loop thread then it might impact the performance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am able to use `logstash-logback-encoder` by referring to https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder/tree/logstash-logback-encoder-6.6#readme in section `Examples using Markers:` . This eliminated custom code to convert the message and key values conversion to json. I tested the performance and it is really good and no need of reactive/async for my use case.

**Sample Code**

```
import java.util.Map;

import static net.logstash.logback.marker.Markers.appendEntries;

@Test
public void logTest(){
    Map<String, String> map = ImmutableMap.of("p1", "v1", "p2", "v2");
    log.info(appendEntries(map), "startTest 100");
    log.info("startTest {} , key1={}, key2= {}", 101, "v1", "v2");
    log.info(appendEntries(map), "startTest {} , key1={}, key2= {}", 101, "v1", "v2");
    log.info("startTest 102");
    log.error(appendEntries(map), "error occured", new RuntimeException());
}
```

**Sample logback configuration**

*Note: `<logstashMarkers/>` is required to log the Map as key values in the json log output.*

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
      <providers>
          <timestamp/>
          <logLevel/>
          <contextName/>
          <threadName>
              <fieldName>thread</fieldName>
          </threadName>
          <callerData>
              <fieldName>src</fieldName>
              <classFieldName>class</classFieldName>
              <methodFieldName>method</methodFieldName>
              <fileFieldName>file</fileFieldName>
              <lineFieldName>line</lineFieldName>
          </callerData>
          <logstashMarkers/>
          <pattern>
              <pattern>
                  {
                      "message": "%message"
                  }
              </pattern>
          </pattern>
          <stackTrace>
              <throwableConverter class="net.logstash.logback.stacktrace.ShortenedThrowableConverter">
                  <maxDepthPerThrowable>30</maxDepthPerThrowable>
                  <maxLength>2048</maxLength>
                  <shortenedClassNameLength>20</shortenedClassNameLength>
                  <exclude>^sun\.reflect\..*\.invoke</exclude>
                  <exclude>^net\.sf\.cglib\.proxy\.MethodProxy\.invoke</exclude>
                  <rootCauseFirst>true</rootCauseFirst>
              </throwableConverter>
          </stackTrace>
      </providers>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

**Performance test**

Added the following performance test and it took ~ **0.08286483 milli seconds = 82864.8304 nano seconds per log message *on average***.

```
private static Map<String, Object> getMap(){
    int count = 5;
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for(int i=0; i<count; ++i){
        map.put("key"+i, UUID.randomUUID());
    }
    return map;
}

@Test
public void logPerformanceTest(){
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    final int COUNT = 10000;
    for(int i=0; i<COUNT; i++) {
        log.info(appendEntries(getMap()), "startTest 100");
    }
    long time = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println("###### TOOK " + time + " (ns) ");
}
```